# Can't get process.start() to work with UNC path on customer's domain

Tags: c#, winforms

From a winforms app, I am trying to open a document stored on a shared drive accessed by UNC.  It works fine on my network, but fails on my client's network.  If I check to make sure the file exists, it says it does, but when I try to open it I get an error message saying

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   The system cannot find the file
>   specified    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo)

Here's the code...

```
// path = "\\server\folder with spaces\"
// fileName = "test.txt"

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path + fileName)) {
  MessageBox.Show("The file " + fileName + " cannot be found.", "Remove File", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
else
{
  System.Diagnostics.Process myProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = path + fileName;
  myProcess.Start();    // FAILS HERE WITH 'SYSTEM CANNOT FIND THE FILE SPECIFIED' ERROR ON CUSTOMER'S NETWORK, WORKS FINE ON MY NETWORK
}
```

I have tried every combination of StartInfo options I can think of, and can't figure out why it finds the file with the `System.IO.File.Exists()`, but fails to find it on the `process.Start();`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Forgot to add - when I run "\\server\folder with spaces\test.txt" from Start, Run...on the customer's domain, it works just fine.

Comment: For opening non-executable files, you need to have UseShellExecute property to be true. Default value is as such true but you may anyway cross check the same.

Comment: VinayC - I tried that too, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So, trying to access the file using a UNC path failed.
Switching it to use a mapped path worked.  I kinda hate doing it that way, but the mapping is part of the corporate environment so I don't think it will be changing any time soon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this falls into what you're seeing, but check [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2004/12/30/344554.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0) out for trusting a share. Relevant information:

> Since network shares by default only get LocalIntranet permissions,
> it's relatively common to want to use CasPol to fully trust some
> shares that you control and know are safe.  However, CasPol syntax
> being what it is, the command to do this isn't immediately obvious.
> If I wanted to trust everything on the share \ShawnFa-Srv\Tools, the
> command:
>
> CasPol.exe -m -ag 1.2 -url file://\ShawnFa-Srv/Tools/* FullTrust
>
> Would setup the policy to do what I needed.  Lets break down this
> command:
>
> **-m**  - modify the machine level of the policy.  This is needed, since the machine level is where all of the default policy lives.  On NT
> platforms it's also the default level that CasPol works with, however
> on Win9x, CasPol will default to the user level, so putting -m in the
> command line explicitly tells CasPol to use the correct level.
>
> **-ag 1.2**  - add a code group under group 1.2.  In the default policy, group 1.2 is the LocalIntranet group, so the new code group that we're
> creating will only be checked if the file comes from the intranet.
>
> **-url file://\ShawnFa-Srv/Tools/***  - The membership condition for the new code group should be a UrlMembershipCondition, and it should match
> anything with a URL that starts with file://ShawnFa-Srv/Tools, meaning
> that any file on the \ShawnFa-Srv\Tools share will match this code
> group.
>
> **FullTrust**  - The permission set to grant assemblies that match the
> code group.  In this case, FullTrust.

Note that .NET 3.5 SP1 [fixed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brada/net-framework-3-5-sp1-allows-managed-code-to-be-launched-from-a-network-share) this.  This is only supposed to be for .NET executables running from a share, but might not hurt seeing if this helps your situation. [Vance Morrison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/) states:

> So I do encourage you to down load the [.NET 3.5 SP1 service pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22).  It
> is a very low risk, drop-in update for the runtime.  Once you do this,
> you get network launch for free.   Because it is a service pack, you
> can also simply just wait, and get the update automatically in the
> next several weeks via windows update.    Thus if you are software
> deployer, pretty soon now, with high probability your customers will
> have this newer runtime.